# Calendar Printing Assistant for Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, printing, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

I depend on printouts of my monthly calendar.  Outlook's default "print style" for printing calendars is terrible (the header shows current and next month, not last month and next month; the first event of the day fills the entire day, leaving off all remaining events - CPA cuts events off at 2 lines).

When I still had Office 2007, CPA worked.

Due to circumstances beyond my control I am now stuck with Office 2016, but CPA does not work with Outlook 2016!

I found instructions for how to make CPA work with Office 2013, but those instructions don't work for 2016.  The MS knowledge base article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2898576) instructs me to create a new registry key in the following folder:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\ProductVersion`

That folder doesn't exist in 2016.  Creating the key allows CPA to run, but it doesn't see any Outlook calendars.

edited to add:
64-bit. the only version of CPA i was able to find says it's for office 2007 (version 12.0.6520.3001)

Comment: Is it a 32 or 64-bit version of Office that's installed?  Which version of CPA are you attempting to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a look at [Outlook Calendar Print](https://www.outlookcalendarprint.com)

[www.OutlookCalendarPrint.com](https://www.outlookcalendarprint.com)

It´s a plugin for Outlook 2010/2013/2016 which enable you to print 1-12 month on one page and you will be able to select which categories you want to print.